# Hudson is not getting latest code from repository

Tags: svn, hudson, nant

I am using Hudson for my my .NET project build with nAnt. I configure simply NAnt executable path and SVN repository path but when I try to Build through Hudson it always says successfully build!!

Although it shows there new change in the file but not showing the error Why ????

Comment: Are you sure you are updating against the correct trunk/branch?

Comment: Paste your console log here

Answer (score 0):

check whether your data/time settings on your build server are consistent with your svn server.

Comment: Actually I have to bind my build steps ( either with NAnt or MSBuild) I am new that was my first step in Hudson.:)